# Wikidata SPARQL with optional qualifiers

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I am trying to adapt the [Mona Lisa exercise in the Wikidata SPARQL tutorial](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial#Qualifiers) so it will show all the materials used and where they apply.

If I simply do:

```
SELECT ?painting ?paintingLabel ?material ?materialLabel 
WHERE
{
  ?painting p:P186 [ ps:P186 ?material].
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  FILTER (?painting = wd:Q12418)
}
```

[Link to this query.](http://tinyurl.com/y6jjrmb9)

then I will see the 3 materials that make up the painting.

If I now edit that query to include P518 (applies to part), I only see the 2 materials that have the P518 qualifier:

```
SELECT ?painting ?paintingLabel ?material ?materialLabel ?appliesTo ?appliesToLabel
WHERE
{
  ?painting p:P186 [ ps:P186 ?material; pq:P518 ?appliesTo].
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  FILTER (?painting = wd:Q12418)
}
```

[Link to this query](http://tinyurl.com/y3my7ht2)

How can I handle the fact that the P518 qualifier is optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ?painting ?paintingLabel ?material ?materialLabel ?appliesTo ?appliesToLabel {
  VALUES (?painting) {(wd:Q12418)}
  ?painting p:P186 ?statement .
  ?statement ps:P186 ?material 
  OPTIONAL { ?statement pq:P518 ?appliesTo }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I noticed you changed the ```FILTER (?painting = wd:Q12418)``` to ```VALUES (?painting) {(wd:Q12418)}```. What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: @AlanBuxton, `VALUES` is more conventional way for providing inline data: see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data In general, optimizer can rewrite a query in order to avoid checking all solutions via `FILTER`, but not always.